# Lifetime context binding to function

Tags: javascript

I asked myself if it is possible to bind a context to a function for all time.

Let's say, we have a global function and a myClass function:

```
function myClass() {
  this.iterator = 1;
}

function incrementConcreteIterator() {
  this.iterator++;
}
```

I now want to call incrementConcreteIterator within the context of myClass, I do:

```
let myClassInstance = new myclass();
incrementConcreteIterator.call(myClassInstance);
incrementConcreteIterator.call(myClassInstance);
//myClassInstance.iterator is now 3
```

And everything works fine. My expectation now was, when I bind myClassInstance, incrementConcreteIterator will always be called within the class context, but it is not.

```
let myClassInstance = new myclass();
incrementConcreteIterator.bind(myClassInstance);
incrementConcreteIterator();
incrementConcreteIterator();
//myClassInstance.iterator is still 1
```

Is there a way, of binding the context to incrementConcreteIterator forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function with the `this` value (and optionally, other parameters) bound, rather than altering the original function, so you need to use it thusly:

```js
function myClass() {
  this.iterator = 1;
}

function incrementConcreteIterator() {
  this.iterator++;
}

let myClassInstance = new myClass();
let myClassInstanceIterator = incrementConcreteIterator.bind(myClassInstance);
myClassInstanceIterator();
myClassInstanceIterator();

console.log(myClassInstance.iterator);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.bind()` returns a new function, you need to assign it to something.

```
let myClassInstance = new myclass();
myInstanceIterator = incrementConcreteIterator.bind(myClassInstance);
myInstanceIterator();
myInstanceIterator();
// myClassInstance.iterator is now 3
```

If you really want to change `incrementConcreteIterator` you could do:

```
incrementConcreteIterator = incrementConcreteIterator.bind(myClassInstance);
```